# Qual o menor peso consulta direta ou usando views para um relacionamento duplo?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Dado o seguinte **schema** hipotético:

```
create table cidade(
  cidade_id integer primary key not null,
  nome varchar(40)
);

create table envios(
   id integer primary key not null,
   cidade_origem_id  integer,
   cidade_destino_id integer
);
alter table envios add foreign key (cidade_origem_id) references cidade (cidade_id);
alter table envios add foreign key (cidade_destino_id) references cidade (cidade_id);

insert into cidade values (1, 'Barbacema');
insert into cidade values (2, 'Los Angeles');
insert into cidade values (3, 'São Paulo');
insert into cidade values (4, 'Porto Velho');

insert into envios values (1, 1,2);
insert into envios values (2, 2,3);
insert into envios values (3, 3,4);

create view cidade_origem as select * from cidade;
create view cidade_destino as select * from cidade;
```

Para buscar os envios por origem e destino tenho a seguinte **query:**

```
select co.nome origem, cd.nome destino from envios e
inner join cidade co on co.cidade_id = e.cidade_origem_id
inner join cidade cd on cd.cidade_id = e.cidade_destino_id
```

O que pesaria mais? Deixar a consulta como está ou utilizar duas **views** (uma para cidade de origem e outra para cidade de destino), e fazer os **joins** com essas **views**?

```
select co.nome origem, cd.nome destino from envios e
inner join cidade_origem co on co.cidade_id = e.cidade_origem_id
inner join cidade_destino cd on cd.cidade_id = e.cidade_destino_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vejo a necessidade de criação de nenhuma `VIEW` no seu caso. E, na verdade, a criação de uma `VIEW` não materializada poderia degradar ainda mais a performance.

Por exemplo, mesmo especificando a cláusula `WHERE` para uma consulta na `VIEW` que você chamou de `cidade_origem`, por "baixo dos panos", um `SELECT * FROM envios;` está sendo executado.

Minha sugestão é que você continue com os seus `JOINS` e crie índices nos campos `cidade_origem_id` e `cidade_destino_id` na  tabela `envios`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_envios_cidade_origem ON envios (cidade_origem_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_envios_cidade_destino ON envios (cidade_destino_id);
```

Atenção, o `PostgreSQL` cria indíces implícitos em chaves primárias, mas não faz o mesmo em chaves entrangeiras.

Outra dica de ouro, é sempre evitar "adivinhar" onde haverá gargalos. Gargalos precisam ser detectadps e identificados, para só então se pensar em otimizações. Você fez o que as "boas práticas" te disseram, agora **espere** os gargalos gritarem.